# Is there a way to toggle variables in for statement?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java, and using this for statement for looping:

```
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++){ 
...
}
```

I'm wanting to toggle a fill color every time the loop runs.  I'm not wanting to give too many examples, because I'm not looking for the answer to my specific issue, but I want to know if there is a way of doing this?

Basically evey odd time the loop runs, it does x and every even time it runs, it does y?

EDIT: after typing this, I'm thinking maybe I can do an if statement with the int i?  something like `if i % 2 == 0 {}` 
?

PS: I am hereby expressing my excitement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a mod operator. If i % 2 == 0 then do something for even, else do something for odd.

Comment: I believe so. :) Have fun coding!

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        //even, do Y
    } else {
        //odd, do X
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the compiler optimizes that statement, and I know that micro optimization is the mother of all evil, but you could use a boolean variable to control your state:

```
boolean gray = false;
for(...) {
    if(gray) {
    } else {
    }
    gray != gray;
}
```

In real life I would probably mod it by 2, as the examples in here, but there are always alternatives.

Comment: FWIW: Micro optimizations are held to be the "root" of all evil... but, that said, I think that reasoning about common idioms and getting in the habit of using the one most likely to deliver the best performance *when they are otherwise equivalent* is something that separates the hacks from the truly good programmers.  Just my 2c.

Comment: There is something to be said for this over using a relatively expensive division... unless, of course, the compiler spots `((x%2)==0)` (or `==1`) and turns it into what I answered.

Comment: There was a question here about checking if a string was blank or not, and all of the answers involved trimming the string and checking the its length. A while ago I checked the source code of StringUtils.isBlank (from Commons-Lang), and they don't trim the string, they actually check if it has anything else than spaces from beginning to end. The trim method would probably do that and return a new string, and by doing it that way they will prevent a new object from being created.

Answer (score 1):

Just going for my *micro-optimization so shoot me* badge, and for a complete set of alternatives to this question:

```
for(int xa=0; xa<3; xa++) { 
    if((xa&0x1)==0) {
        // even
        }
    else {
        // odd
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really like your answer. Never thought of that before, but, of course, if the last bit is 1 it's odd otherwise it's even.